# Calling MySQL procedure from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

As an example, suppose I want to execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts;
```

Therefore, I write the following:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_posts`(IN `zip` INT)
  LANGUAGE SQL
  NOT DETERMINISTIC
  CONTAINS SQL
  SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.zip = zip;
END
```

Is the following change the only one I have to make:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts");
// to
mysql_query("CALL get_posts");
```

...and then I can fetch rows, etc.?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Answer (score 6):

you also need to supply the parameter

```
mysql_query("CALL get_posts(11)");
```

another suggestion is by using **[`PDO` extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** on this.

Example of using PDO,

```
<?php
    $zipCode = 123;
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL get_posts(?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $zipCode);
    if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['columnName']))) 
    {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
        {
            print_r($row);
        }
    }
?>
```

this will protect you from **[SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)**.

Answer (score 5):

Your procedure expects an input parameter, so call it with one:

```
$result = mysql_query("CALL get_posts(12345)");
```

This will supply a result resource on a successful call, then you can run a fetch loop as you would a normal query.

```
if ($result) {
  // fetch in a while loop like you would any normal SELECT query...
}
```